# ASP.NET Scroll or Cooler Animation on Element Visibility

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Since it is possible to show/hide asp html elements without using JavaScript in ASP.net, is it possible to extend that capability so that the show/hide will look cooler with scroll or shrinking animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing/hiding HTML elements in asp.net is done on the server. A hidden element is either not present in the HTML source at all or is marked invisible using the CSS `Visibility` attribute.

Scrolling or shrinking has to be done on the client, and the most obvious runtime there is Javascript. To achieve your effects I recommend using [jQuery](http://jquery.com).

Comment: so will jQuery capable of integrate into ASP.NET much easier than normal Javascript?

Comment: Certainly. Take a look at the jquery.com home page and click on the "Run code" button. You can't imagine such an animation with a code so short. You can trigger a client-side animation by adding a jquery call in a ASP.NET element's OnClientClick handler for example.

Comment: jQuery IS normal Javascript. It is a framework built in JS that makes using JS easier, particularly the effects-based DOM manipulation you're talking about.